# pgfplots line doesn't reach axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
        width=500,
        height=500,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        zmin=-5,
        zmax=0.5,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        view = {100}{10},
        xtick={-4,0, 4},
        ytick={-4,0,4},
        ztick={0,-3,-5}
        ]
        \addplot3[black, samples=40, domain=-4:4,thick, samples y=0]({x},{0},{(-5*x^2)/16});

        \addplot3[black, samples=40, domain=-4:0,thick]({0},{y},{(-5*y^2)/16});

        \addplot3[black, samples=40,         domain=-4:4,samples y=0    ]({x},{0},{-sqrt(x^2+9)});
        \addplot3[black, samples=40, dashed, domain=-4:0                ]({0},{y},{-sqrt(y^2+9)});

        \addplot3[black, samples=20, dashed, domain=-4:0,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+16)},{-5});
        \addplot3[black, samples=20,         domain= 0:4,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+16)},{-5});

        \addplot3[black, samples=40, dashed, domain=-4:0 ,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+ 9.6)},{-3});
        \addplot3[black, samples=40,         domain= 0:4 ,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+ 9.6))},{-3});

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And why is doesn't reach another line?

Comment: Also, if you know another easier way to draw bodies, like this, please tell me how

Comment: Please add complete compilable code starting, with `\documentclass{...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not take `sqrt` of a negative number. I have adjusted your domain.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
        width=500,
        height=500,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        zlabel = {$z$},
        zmin=-5,
        zmax=0.5,
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=4,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        view = {100}{10},
        xtick={-4,0, 4},
        ytick={-4,0,4},
        ztick={0,-3,-5}
        ]
        \addplot3[black, samples=40, domain=-4:4,thick, samples y=0]({x},{0},{(-5*x^2)/16});

        \addplot3[black, samples=40, domain=-4:0,thick]({0},{y},{(-5*y^2)/16});

        \addplot3[black, samples=40,         domain=-4:4,samples y=0    ]({x},{0},{-sqrt(x^2+9)});
        \addplot3[black, samples=40, dashed, domain=-4:0                ]({0},{y},{-sqrt(y^2+9)});

        \addplot3[black, samples=20, dashed, domain=-4:0,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+16)},{-5});
        \addplot3[black, samples=20,         domain= 0:4,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+16)},{-5});

        \addplot3[black, samples=40, dashed, domain=-sqrt(9.6):0 ,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+ 9.6)},{-3});
        \addplot3[black, samples=40,         domain= 0:sqrt(9.6) ,samples y=0    ]({x},{-sqrt(-x^2+ 9.6))},{-3});

        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Corrected graph]

Comment: How is it possible to have `samples y=0` and even the funtion is drawn?

Comment: @manooooh: I do not know, and I thought it was an error, but it does have some meaning, as it is used in example on page 57 in the manual.